# Como criar um regex para remover linhas com #?

Tags: php, regex

Estou começando com regex agora então não sou muito bom ainda com expressões, supondo que eu tenha a seguinte variável:

```
$foo = "
        #01 = linha comentada; 
        02 = valor para ser interpretado; 
        #03 = outra linha comentada;
       ";
```

Como criar um regex para remover as linhas 01 e 03 deixando apenas a linha 02 para ser interpretada no futuro?
Obs: Cada linha termina no `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugestão:

```
<?php
$foo = "
    #01 = linha comentada; 
    02 = valor para ser interpretado; 
    #03 = outra linha comentada;
";
$limpa = preg_replace('/[\s\t]*#\d+[^;]+;/im', '', $foo);
echo $limpa;

?>
```

A ideia da regex é:

- `[\s\t]*` espaços ou tabs, zero ou mais
- `#` o caractere `#`
- `\d+` um dígito, uma ou mais vezes
- `[^;]+` qualquer caractere excluíndo `;` uma ou mais vezes
- `;` o caractere `;`

**Exemplo: https://ideone.com/YssIgR**

Comment: Obrigado por postar o regex explicado, o mesmo funciona com JS?

Comment: @LeoLetto basicamente é o mesmo, usa a flag `g`: https://jsfiddle.net/yq0vvwcj/